# Is there a way to order elements in 2 different arrays based on only one, but not put them in the exact order?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a number array of 345678, and another number array of 386. I want to compare 386 to 345678. The comparison would realize that 386 does exist in the array 345678. However 386 is not in order in 345678. They don't necessarily have to be in order next to each other, but just in order in the array. So the code should rearrange 345678 as 345876 that way now 386 is in order in the number 345678. Is this something that is even possible? I understand that I can do a search, and sort, but that would put the numbers 386 in order in 345678 as 386457, and that is not what I want.

I have not tried coding this. I was just wondering if a concept like this was even possible.

Comment: When you say "number", do you mean "digit"? Are the "arrays" you are talking about strings?

Comment: Yes essentially. Both of the numbers were be in an array.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But as far as I know there is no shortcut; you must code it.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the function [`std::strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strspn)? The function call `std::strspn( "386", "345678" );` will return `3` indicating that all `3` characters of `"386"` exist inside the string `"345678"`, so the comparison can be considered true. If you want to use `std::string` instead of a C-style null-terminated `char` array, you can use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of), which will return `std::string::npos` if the comparison is true.

Comment: Is the reordering you are talking about supposed to be permanent? Or only temporary for the purpose of comparison?

Comment: Why is the correct rearrangement `345876` and not, say, `386457`, or many other sequences that have `386` as a subsequence?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel This problem is actually from a project Euler #79 Passcode Derivation. It is for a secure coding class, and we are not allowed to use std::string. We have to solve the problem by using a c-style null-terminated char array. The re ordering is also supposed to be permanent as another number would be read into fileNum, and compared again. if the currentNum is 345678, and the fileNum being compared is 386. Then the indices of 386 have to match that of 345678, but they don't necessarily have to be together. so currentNum should update as 345876 so that 386 are still in order the #.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The correct arrangement would be 345876. The numbers don't have to be together. The should just be in order. 386 has indexes 0,1,2. the 386 in the larger number (345678) has indexes 0, 3, 5(368) and is not in order. the index of the 8 and the 6 is not in the right order. That is why the correct arrangement should be 345876.

Comment: I see. You want to rearrange 3, 6 and 8 in 386 order, while keeping other elements in their original places. Yes, this can be done; it's reasonably straightforward.